# How to leave MouseListener on ChildComponent but correctly keep track of mouse enter and exit on parent?

Tags: java, swing, layout, components, cardlayout

I have a JPanel with a CardLayout and two cards. I want the layout to flip the cards each time the mouse enters or exits the panel. 
This works fine unless one of the cards is a component that listens for mouse events. Consider the following example:

```
JPanel cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel(layout);
JButton button = new JButton("listening!");
JLabel label = new JLabel("not listening.");
cardLayoutPanel.add(button);
cardLayoutPanel.add(label);
layout.last(cardLayoutPanel);
cardLayoutPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("entered!");
        layout.next(cardLayoutPanel);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("exited!");
        layout.next(cardLayoutPanel);
    }
});
```

The problem is that, if the MouseEvent is catched by a child component, it is not processed by the parent as a read in many SO-questions related to this topic. 
I tried different things like redispatching the event or just ignoring the exit event if the event if the event coordinates are still in the panel.

The first solution does not work at all, the second neither since then the mouse entered event does not occur anymore.

How can i solve this?

The only solution that I see right now would be to completely remove the listener from the child component and perform the collision and event handling on my own in the parents mouse mouse listener, but this would be a mess and not the intended way to do this, i guess.

Any help or ideas appreciated.

EDIT: here is a complete short compilable example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class CardLayoutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50)));

        CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
        JPanel cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel(layout);
        JButton button = new JButton("listening!");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("not listening.");
        cardLayoutPanel.add(button);
        cardLayoutPanel.add(label);
        layout.last(cardLayoutPanel);
        cardLayoutPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("entered!");
                layout.next(cardLayoutPanel);
            }


            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("exited!");
                layout.next(cardLayoutPanel);
            }
        });

        content.add(cardLayoutPanel);
        frame.add(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mouse events are a pain. Just adding a mouse listener prevents the event propagating down the component tree! Where there are PL&Fs, you cannot be sure what is happening. Redispatch as "glass pane" should work.

Comment: I know, this is exactly the problem here. What does PL&Fs mean? And what do you mean by "redispatch as 'glass pane' " ?

Comment: PL&F Plugable Look and Feel - the code that make the GUI look like a particular platform, whether Windows, Metal, Gtk or whatever. There should be plenty of examples out there referring to a glass pane, which is a component over the top of a container that intercepts mouse events as they go through.

Comment: okay thank you, i will look if i can make it run with this approach

Answer (score 1):

I modified your example slightly and got it to work.  The key (at least in this example), was to have the button share the same `mouseListener` with the `cardLayoutPanel`.  I do not know if this is a universal solution but it does work here.  I also made the following changes:

1. added a private innner class for the mouseListener.
2. Increased the size of the cardLayoutPanel.
3. Added color borders to the Label and Button.

```
    import java.awt.CardLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

    public class CardLayoutTest {

        JButton button = new JButton("listening!");
        JPanel cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
        CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new CardLayoutTest().start();
        }

        public void start() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            JPanel content = new JPanel();
            content.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(
                    new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50)));

            cardLayoutPanel.setLayout(layout);
            cardLayoutPanel
                    .setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            button.addActionListener(
                    ae -> System.out.println("IT WORKS!"));
            button.removeMouseMotionListener(
                    button.getMouseMotionListeners()[0]);
            button.removeMouseListener(
                    button.getMouseListeners()[0]);

            MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();
            button.addMouseListener(ml);
            button.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 2));
            JLabel label = new JLabel("not listening.");
            label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2));
            cardLayoutPanel.add(button);
            cardLayoutPanel.add(label);
            layout.last(cardLayoutPanel);
            cardLayoutPanel.addMouseListener(ml);

            content.add(cardLayoutPanel);
            frame.add(content);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(
                    JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("entered!");
                    layout.next(cardLayoutPanel);

            }
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                    JButton b = (JButton)(e.getSource());
                    b.doClick();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("exited!");
                    layout.next(cardLayoutPanel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! I will look if a can get your solution to run tomorrow.

Comment: OK.  One observation.  I used the `button` instance in the main program to `click` the button.  A better way would be to get the source from the `MouseEvent` and cast it to a JButton and then use that to do a `doClick`.  That way they can all share the same `mouseListener`  Actually, I just tried it out to ensure the syntax so I will amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quiet a good solution but i managed to achieve what i want by calling the flip event when *entering* the *parent component.* This works since i have enough space between my panels with this property.

I did not, however, managed to achieve this effect with glass panes as suggested in a comment. Maybe I was doing it wrong, but the events did not arrive at the components properly, even some instanceof checks failed out of nowhere.

If someone knows how to do this properly I would be glad to see.